# Tesseract command for PHP is not not found

Tags: php

Tesseract command in PHP does not work even installing the Actual executable Tesseract software. Is there any alternatives to Tesseract PHP? I want to scan and extract text from an image inside PDF File

Comment: What is "Tesseract command for PHP"? Please provide reference.

Comment: https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php is not working for me and I want alternatives for this library

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all those clarifications, comments are for asking for clarifications, not for providing them. And if you're in for a tip, show a short example of how you call / invoke that library so it becomes more visible where you get the error so users can give actual answers. Looking for alternatives is often too broad, better take your concrete example and ask about a concrete error or problem.

Answer (score 2):

To work with Tesseract you also need to install PHP extensions like `tesseract-ocr` and `tesseract-ocr-YOUR-LANG`

Moreover, it does not work with PDF directly, so first the PDF must be converted to images (for example, using `imagemagick` + `ghostscript`)

For example for Polish (pol) and France (fra) languages:

```bash
apt-get install -y \
imagemagick \
ghostscript \
tesseract-ocr \
tesseract-ocr-pol \
tesseract-ocr-fra
```

Allow work with PDF (fix error like "attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF") by edit
/etc/imagemagick-6/policy.xml (or /etc/imagemagick-YOUR-VERSION/policy.xml)

```
- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
+ <policy domain="coder" rights="reader | write" pattern="PDF" />
```

And then you can use thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php, or even use the raw implementation:

Step 1. PDF to images:

```php
$page = 0;
do {
    $sCmd = sprintf("convert 2>&1 -density 300 -depth 8 \"$file\"[$page] $folder/page%03d.jpg", $page);
    exec($sCmd, $stub, $result);
    $page++;
} while ($result === 0);
```

Step 2. Images to txt:

```php
private function getFiles($folder, $ext) {
    return glob("$folder/*.$ext");
}

$images = $this->getFiles($folder, 'jpg');

foreach ($images as $imagePath) {
    $cmd = "tesseract \"$imagePath\" \"$imagePath\" -l eng+pol+fra quiet";
    exec($cmd, $output, $iResult);
}
```

Step 3. Combine text files:

```php
$result = '';
foreach($this->getFiles($folder, 'txt') as $v){
    $text = file_get_contents($v);
    $result .= $text;
}
```

If your PDFs have a text layer (with good quality), then you can consider alternatives like poppler-utils, smalot/pdfparser, ottosmops/pdftotext. They show much higher speed, but can't work with images. And I guess this won't interest you much.